# Double Click open dialog on ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to open the dialog box to a custom plugin via a doubleclick on a placeholder.

```js
        editor.on('doubleclick',
                function (event) {

                    var element = event.data.element;

                    if (element.is('div')) {

                        event.data.dialog = 'sharedcontent';
                    }
                    console.log('clicked!');

                });
```

Here is the doubleclick function I'm using, and it is currently registering.

So I feel there is a referencing issue with the actual dialog box.

Has anyone else run into this issue and know a way around it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Error was a reference issue, renamed the reference and now the dialog box appears